# API passes in as null

Tags: c#, api

I have a known working API. When I call it using code below it passes in as NULL values.

code:

```
public bool Serial_Key_Exist(WBG_Serial_Key Serial_Key)
    {
        bool exists = false;
        string verification = string.Empty;
        string uri = _EndPoint + "api/WhiteBoXGaming/Post_SerialKeyExist";
        var ujson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Serial_Key);
        var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = ujson.Length;

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(ujson);
        }

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            verification = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        if (verification == "true") { exists = true; }

        return exists;
    }
```

Something wrong with my call to my api? Here is the class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class WBG_Serial_Key
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Serial_Key { get; set; }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Anyone have suggestions?

Update:
I adjusted code as suggested still not working:

```
public bool Serial_Key_Exist(string serial)
    {
        bool rsp = false;
        WBG_Serial_Key Serial_Key = new WBG_Serial_Key();
        Serial_Key.Email = "";
        Serial_Key.Product = _Product;
        Serial_Key.Serial_Key = serial;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_EndPoint);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/WhiteBoXGaming/Post_SerialKeyExist", rsp).Result;

            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().Result;
            }

            //default failed - Prevent duplicate keys 
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Here is the APi code:

```
 [Route("api/WhiteBoXGaming/Post_SerialKeyExist")]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool SerialKeyExist([FromBody]WBG_Serial_Key Key)
    {
        bool Exist = false;

        Exist = _DataHelper.Serial_Key_Exist(Key.Serial_Key, Key.Product);

        return Exist;
    }
```

Update:
now I have a new issue it keeps dead locking now. Anyway to get the return result without using async?

Comment: Perhaps your API code is wrong instead? I see a lot of people trying to accept JSON server-side with something like `ApiMethod(string myJsonBody)` which, of course, doesn't work and then they wonder why they get `null`.

Comment: also, `WebRequest` is [not recommended to be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netcore-3.1#remarks), use `HttpClient` instead

Comment: Well post a sample code if you think your idea will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working thanks for everyone's help and suggestions.

```
public bool Serial_Key_Exist(string serial)
    {
        bool rsp = false;
        WBG_Serial_Key Serial_Key = new WBG_Serial_Key();
        Serial_Key.Email = "";
        Serial_Key.Product = _Product;
        Serial_Key.Serial_Key = serial;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_EndPoint);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/WhiteBoXGaming/Post_SerialKeyExist", Serial_Key).Result;

            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().Result;
            }

            //default failed - Prevent duplicate keys 
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: So it wasn't a server-side issue? Interesting. I recommend reading [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and the follow-up [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/). It goes into why you shouldn't use `HttpClient` with `using` in the way that you are, how Microsoft intended it to be static for the entire application, and how doing...

Comment: ...that causes issues with DNS not staying up-to-date in longer-lifetime applications. Microsoft have created a solution for it, and that's all covered in the follow-up article.